# difference between Fisher–Yates shuffle and reservoir sampling

Tags: algorithm, math, shuffle

I know F-Y and reservoir sampling can both achieve shuffle array. For example, we deploy k bombs in a minesweeping board of m * n.

I have finished the sample code:

```
public int[][] init2(int width, int length, int num){
    int[][] board = int[width][length];
    int[] bomb = new int[num];
    for(int i =0; i<num; i++){
        bomb[i] = i;
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = num; i<width*length; i++){
        int pos = rand.nextInt(i);
        if(pos < num){
            bomb[pos] = i;
        }
    }
    // TO DO
    // and then restore the pos to board        
}

// Fisher–Yates shuffle
public int[][] init3(int width, int length, int num){
    int[][] board = int[width][length];
    for(int i =0; i<num; i++){
        board[i%width][i/width] = 1;
    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    for(int i = num; i<width*length; i++){
        int pos = rand.nextInt(i+1);
        swap(board, i, pos);        
    }   
}

public void swap(int[][] board, int pos1, int pos2){
    int temp = board[pos1%width][pos1/width];
    board[pos1%width][pos1/width] = board[pos2%width][pos2/width];
    board[pos2%width][pos2/width] = temp;
}
```

I think the math behind both is the same, but I don't know why. 
Btw, it seems we don't need to use markdown if we input code on stackoverflow. Amazing!

Comment: Did you do any research on this question before you asked?  The Wikipedia page on reservoir sampling has a section on how it relates to the Fischer-Yates shuffle. Also, this isn't a question; the fact that you don't understand something isn't a *question*. What is your *specific question*?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see the wiki. Your comment is helpful!

Answer (score 3):

The difference between the two is that they do different things:

```
+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
| ALGORITHM    | INPUT(S)       | OUTPUT                      | TIME | SPACE |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
| FISHER-YATES | n elements     | A list containing all n     | O(n) | O(n)  |
| SHUFFLE      |                | elements in a random order  |      |       |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
| RESERVOIR    | n elements and | A set containing k of the n | O(n) | O(k)  |
| SAMPLING     | an integer k   | elements, selected randomly |      |       |
+--------------+----------------+-----------------------------+------+-------+
```

For your Minesweeper example, you have *m* × *n* cells and want to choose *k* of them, which is exactly what reservoir sampling does. So it seems conceptually more appropriate to me. But since you intend to use *O*(*m* × *n*) space *anyway*, and since your entire problem is probably not big enough to really worry about performance, I think the Fisher–Yates approach is fine, too. (They are both mathematically sound.)